# Using variables in "Dynamics CRM Source" fetchXML in SSIS

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, fetchxml, kingswaysoft

I am building SSIS package in that package I am using "Dynamics CRM Source" control which uses fetchXML to retrieve data from MS Dynamics CRM.

This is my fetchXML:

```
<fetch> 
  <entity name='f1_workorder'> 
     <all-attributes /> 
     <filter type='and'> 
        <condition attribute='createdon' operator="on-or-after" value="5/5/2018" /> 
     </filter> 
  </entity> 
</fetch>
```

You can see that condition value is hard-coded "5/5/2018"

It suppose to be read from a variable called XMLPeriod.

I tried many ways to use the variable in the fetchXML with no luck.
I tried this

```
<condition attribute='createdon' operator="on-or-after" value=@XMLPeriod />
```

and this

```
<condition attribute='createdon' operator="on-or-after" value="@XMLPeriod" />
```

and this

```
<condition attribute='createdon' operator="on-or-after" value="@[User::XMLPeriod]" />
```

and this

```
<condition attribute='createdon' operator="on-or-after" value=@[User::XMLPeriod] />
```

I get this error

```
'@' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 5, position 71.
```

any idea how to get this working?

Comment: Not working means error or unexpected result?

Comment: @ArunVinoth getting this error '@' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 5, position 71.

Comment: is this error coming for all 4 cases? IIRC 3rd option should work..

Comment: how are you determining a package variable before a Kingswaysoft source component? When I try to connect script component to Dynamics source, it says it has no inputs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Arun has suggested in the comment, the third option (copied below) should work.

`<condition attribute='createdon' operator="on-or-after" value="@[User::XMLPeriod]" />`

If it is not working, please post the entire error message here, so that I can have a further look.

Comment: Macaulay i am getting different error for this one [The date-time format for @[User::XMLPeriod] is invalid, or value is outside the supported range.]

Comment: @asmgx are you passing value to that variable? This error will come even when null or empty string passed to date type..

Comment: @ArunVinoth I am using this expression for the variable 
 << DATEADD("DD", -7, GetDate() ) >>

Comment: @asmgx where did you specify this variable expression? Is " [The date-time format for @[User::XMLPeriod] is invalid, or value is outside the supported range." the exact error message reported by our software?

Comment: @DanielCai I specified it in the variable expression section

Comment: @asmgx please reach out to our technical support using the contact information on http://www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us, someone from our team will have a look of the situation with you remotely. This should be a simple issue.

Comment: @DanielCai the website you reffered to me has problems it cant take script apprantly and crashes when i send the message getting "Server Error in '/' Application." :)

Comment: i changed the variable value to "05/05/2018" but still getting the same error, yet if i just used this inside the XML directly it works fine.!

Comment: Works for me! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you create an SSIS variable like String as FetchXML.

You make your own FetchXML with that variable in that string in a previous step, so you can use the `fetchxml` variable directly in the expression setup:

I think you are using CozyRoc, so you can configure your Fetchxml variable in your component "Dynamic data Flow task plus", into the setup configuration through:
    "Your Dynamic data Flow task plus">Advanced>Expressions>["Name of your data Flow task plues"].[@[User::YourVariableFetchXml]

Comment: I tried to format your answer a little but the last part was a little confusing. You might have to [edit] things and make sure you are clear what is code and what is explanation.